# How to render a variable with a tilde on Latex with Sagetex

Tags: python, latex, sage

I have the following Sage variable declared:

```
var('c_tilde')
```

I want to print out that variable as `\tilde{c}` on a Latex Document through Sagetex.

Thus ideally I would be able to do something like follows in a Latex Document:

```
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{sagesilent}
var('c_tilde')
latex_render_as(c_tilde, '\tilde{c}')
\end{sagesilent}

Printing out $\sage{c_tilde}$.
```

And it would render as follows:

```
Printing out $\tilde{c}$.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the latex name.

```
c_tilde = SR.var('c_tilde', latex_name=r'\tilde c')
```

or if you want a larger tilde,

```
c_tilde = SR.var('c_tilde', latex_name=r'\widetilde{c}')
```

To illustrate the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\begin{sagesilent}
c_tilde = SR.var('c_tilde', latex_name=r'\tilde{c}')
c_wilde = SR.var('c_wilde', latex_name=r'\widetilde{c}')
\end{sagesilent}
introducing $\sage{c_tilde}$\par
introducing $\sage{c_wilde}$\par
\end{document}
```